# Mail - Subfolders on own IMAP-Server are all shown under INBOX

Tags: mail.app, email, folders, imap

I've got a problem with my folders within the mail app.
As you can see, I've got three accounts:

- an exchange server
- my iCloud server
- an own imap server

The problem with the IMAP server is, that all of the subfolders are shown under the INBOX and I can't move them to the server-root, because, as you can see down further I have no possibility to move them to the root.

I'm not quite sure wether this is the correct community for this question..
but, would love to hear some tips :)

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try adding a root folder in Accounts under the Advanced tab.

Use INBOX

[image: Add root folder]